# Is supporting Sci-Hub illegal/unacademic?

Tags: publications, academic-freedom, disciplinary-action, sci-hub

In the classroom, one of the students asked me about Sci-Hub. I answered that I like the idea as I am against the tyranny of publishers. As a fun fact, I added that I have even donated to Sci-Hub.

Then, I received a notice from our department head referring the case to the disciplinary committee since Sci-Hub is illegal and any direct and indirect support of an illegal activity is against the university policy.

Is supporting Sci-Hub illegal / unacademic?

Comment: To clarify, your department head referred you to the disciplinary committee?  Also, could you please elaborate on your position (e.g. tenured faculty, tenure track, non tenure track, adjunct, etc).

Comment: Illegal, probably. Unacademic, certainly not. Presenting the two as if they were two facets of the same coin is misleading, though.

Comment: @RichardErickson No, it does not depend on my university's policies if it is illegal or not to support Sci-hub. Universities do not make laws. At most I can break a contractual clause or an ethics code by supporting it, but that's not the same thing as being illegal.

Comment: By the way: which country are you in, OP? That might change the answer.

Comment: It may still be disallowed by the uni via contract with the publisher, no matter how sympathies may run.

Comment: @RichardErickson The main source of confusion is that this question could be stated better. The question in the title is "is supporting Sci-Hub illegal / unacademic", but the implied question that everyone has in their mind when they finish reading this post is "Is the university right? what should I do now?". But the university never claimed that it is illegal/unacademic, just that it is against their policy. We can't answer this because we don't know what this policy is (nor which university OP works in).

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Sci-Hub is pretty clearly illegal, and donating money to it is pretty clearly supporting it. Whether supporting an illegal activity is legal is something outside the scope of Academia.SE. Besides, in your case it's already against the university policy, which you presumably agreed to abide to when you took up your job. I am not sure what else there is to answer.

Comment: You should perhaps rethink your question. How would it help you in your situation if the majority of users here *opined* that supporting scihub was neither unacademic nor illegal?

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction, there may be an important distinction between *illegal* and *unlawful*. This is yet another reason for editing the question to state the relevant jurisdiction.

Comment: I would talk to a lawyer before going in front of the disciplinary committee.

Comment: You could consider clarifying what you mean by "donated".  There is a big difference between giving your own money to Sci-Hub and downloading a paper using your institutions account and uploading this to Sci-Hub.  My guess an assumption of the latter has caused the issue.

Comment: @Allure "Sci-Hub is pretty clearly illegal" is a pretty strong statement. Individual _uploaders_ may have broken their personal contract with a specific publisher, but that does not necessarily make _using it_ illegal. Definitely not "clearly".

Comment: @pipe from what I've seen, laws across the world are tightening around that loophole. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86414/is-it-legal-to-use-sci-hub-cc-in-germany/112475#112475. Besides, the OP wasn't using the service, he was donating to it.

Comment: @Allure "Sci-Hub is pretty clearly illegal," is it? What law has Sci-Hub broken?

Comment: @user2768 it acquires the material illegally?

Comment: @Allure What exactly is illegal about the way material is acquired?

Comment: @user2768 if you aren't familiar with how SciHub acquires its papers, I recommend reading articles like this one. https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone

Comment: @Allure I'm familiar, I'm just questioning which aspect you are asserting is "clearly illegal."

Comment: @user2768 Tell me how SciHub acquires its papers in your own words, otherwise I have no idea how to answer your question.

Comment: @Allure It seems you have no evidence to support your claim: The law is nuanced and whether Sci-Hub is operating illegally is complex to ascertain. Your claim that "Sci-Hub is pretty clearly illegal" is without evidence and I believe false.

Comment: @user2768 it seems you don't understand how SciHub acquires its papers; as long as that is the case I don't see any point responding to you.

Comment: @Allure That doesn't help your argument. I'll leave it there from my side.

Comment: Just curious: how did the disciplinary proceedings turn out?

Answer (score 20):

In my view it is foolish to describe Sci-Hub itself as illegal. Acts can be illegal, but not "things" or groups of people. Only activities. While it is true that they may engage in illegal activities, that is not the same thing.

However, if what they do is copyright infringement (very possibly) then you can't participate in that.

However, if you want to upload things for which you hold copyright to Sci-Hub or a similar site then you aren't engaging in any illegal activity, nor is any downloader, provided that you grant an appropriate license.

Countries and other jurisdictions make laws. People (and organizations) can break those laws, but the people themselves, and the organizations do not themselves become illegal.

I think your university is right to open a disciplinary hearing only if you advocate breaking laws to students.

I agree with you that publishers have put a lock on science and culture that is very unfortunate. Especially when copyright no longer seems to expire after a reasonable period, and fair use is losing ground. Publishers are transferring what should be a common good into a private profit making enterprise. They are, IMO, *stealing* from the public. If you can afford not to give them copyright on things then I encourage it, but the whole system has made it hard for academics to build a reputation otherwise. Long term this tends to make us dumber, not smarter. As they say: Sad.

---

I'll add an historical note. There was once a valid reason for publishers to want to hold copyright on articles they published. There was a lot of friction (read cost) between an author and a potential reader. As such, since the publisher bore a lot of the cost (not the creation cost, of course), they needed assurance that they could recoup what they spent in making scientific articles available - especially since the material itself had value, but the number of potential readers was small (relatively speaking).

But that world is now long past. Publishing is nearly frictionless now. Publishers can still provide a useful review (done by volunteers) and editing (done by paid professionals) function, but the distribution cost is near zero and borne partly by users in any case (internet fees). Most of the real cost of the creation of publishable material today is borne by the author, by universities and scientific organizations, and by government. Publishers in the old model are an anachronism if not an oxymoron.

Comment: *I think your university is right to open a disciplinary hearing only if you advocate breaking laws to students.* In many jurisdictions, copyright infringement is not breaking criminal law, which is what is usually meant by "against the law". Further, they act of *downloading* a paper from Sci-Hub is, in most jurisdictions, not copyright infringement. Rather, Sci-Hub is committing copyright infringement (and possibly other crimes depending on how the paper was obtained).

Comment: The question isn't "is Sci-hub illegal". It's "is giving money to Sci-hub illegal".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, I doubt that there is any law that could be construed that way, but I'm just an academic, not an international lawyer. There are lots of laws. There might be policies against it, and likely are, but contributing money is likely not illegal. In the US, some organizations (the MOB) are designated as Criminal Enterprises, meaning that their whole purpose is to break the law. There might be laws against contributing to such organizations. I think (hope) the bar is set high for creating such a designation. But it is local laws that apply, of course.

Comment: *I think your university is right to open a disciplinary hearing only if you advocate breaking laws to students.* That's exactly what you do if you say you 'like the idea' of and even donate money to an illegal endeavor. (Having said that, I have mixed feelings, including sympathy, toward scihub although it's activities are clearly illegal in most jurisdictions.)

Answer (score 11):

What Sci-Hub itself does is illegal in most jurisdictions.

Whether it is illegal to *download from* Sci-Hub, and whether it is illegal to *donate money to* Sci-Hub, will vary from place to place, and is really a question for experts in law, not an Academia Q&A site.

Whether it is *ethical* to download from Sci-Hub, or donate to Sci-Hub, is a different question, which some would argue is unrelated to the legal situation.

A third question is perhaps whether what you have done, as a private individual, is any of the university's business (I assume that the donations were personal ones and not from university funds?). A fourth question is, if not, whether it becomes their business when you tell a student about it.

It will probably be worth being very clear in your own mind about these distinctions; but pragmatically, it may also be a good time to apologise, and not make a fuss.

Comment: Depending on the legal details, it might be important to differentiate between an apology and an admission of guilt. The latter might bring more trouble.

Comment: _What Sci-Hub itself does is illegal in most jurisdictions_ Why?

Comment: @user2768 it distributes copyrighted material without the permission of the owners.

Comment: @Flyto Whether that is illegal depends on the jurisdiction. I suppose that's why you opted for "most jurisdictions."

Comment: @Flyto: Distributing individual scientific articles to people interested in them is not, to my knowledge, illegal in "most jurisdictions".

Comment: @einpoklum but copyright infringement is. Not every case of distributing scientific literature is copyright infringement, but Scihub doesn't discriminate.

Answer (score -7):

If you think Sci-Hub is a knight in shining armor fighting against the tyranny of publishers, your view of Sci-Hub is incorrect. Sci-Hub is generally illegal, does illegal things, and is a scourge of law-abiding academics & institutions everywhere.

I'm going to skip all the "publishers are/are not tyrants" arguments because I assume you are familiar with them and have already decided publishers are tyrants, and trying to change your mind is futile. However Sci-Hub does illegal things in other ways: it embodies the dark side of the online world by phishing, hacking passwords, stealing as much information as possible, etc. Check [this article](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2018/09/18/guest-post-think-sci-hub-is-just-downloading-pdfs-think-again/) out.

> Let me be clear: Sci-Hub is not just stealing PDFs. They’re phishing, they’re spamming, they’re hacking, they’re password-cracking, and basically doing anything to find personal credentials to get into academic institutions. While illegal access to published content is the most obvious target, this is just the tip of an iceberg concealing underlying efforts to steal multiple streams of personal and research data from the world’s academic institutions.
>
> ...
>
> We know that, at one UK University, Sci-Hub managed to get six passwords through a 48-hour dictionary attack on their system. Then, over a weekend (when spikes in usage are less likely to come to the attention of publishers or library technical departments) they accessed 350 publisher websites and made 45,092 PDF requests. In another attack, the hackers not only broke into their database; they changed the names and passwords of profiles. Another institution told us an intruder changed the cell phone numbers linked to the user accounts and also planted malware, meaning that all their computers needed to be completely wiped. In addition, we have evidence that Sci-Hub is bombarding university IT systems, often for days on end, without the knowledge of compromised users.

If you distrust both publishers and IT experts, try talking to your institution's librarians. It might surprise you that they [dislike Sci-Hub too](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2018/11/09/a-librarian-perspective-on-sci-hub-the-true-solution-to-the-scholarly-communication-crisis-is-in-the-hands-of-the-academic-community-not-librarians/). The article cites several reasons, such as how Sci-Hub stifles innovation in publishing, is parasitic on libraries, puts the library at legal risk, and has no regard for copyright law. Some quotes:

> It can be argued that, far from being disruptive or publishing’s “Napster moment”, by providing access to such material Sci-Hub is stifling the impetus needed to innovate in publishing.
>
> ...
>
> Again, it is ironic that access to the site is provided by the very mechanism it means to subvert. This argument becomes even more extreme when it is taken to its logical conclusion (which all three of us have heard) that we should cancel library subscriptions and rely on Sci-Hub: a major reason Sci-Hub exists is because of the subscriptions we pay for. It is unashamedly illegal and it is parasitic on library subscriptions.
>
> ...
>
> In terms of library access and users donating subscriptions, such action puts access to all our users at risk ... Moreover, university libraries can become liable for breach of their contractual terms if services are misused, or credentials passed on by library users. Typically, contractual terms specify that “Authorised Users must not provide access and/or allow use of the Licensed Material by anyone other than Authorised Users” (or words to that effect). Thus, if a subscribing institution knowingly lets an Authorised User do this, or turns a blind eye to the problem if it is drawn to their attention, then the subscriber is in breach of its contract with the publisher and will be cut off.
>
> ...
>
> Our final objection to Sci-Hub is its utter contempt for copyright law – and this is an important point. Ownership of copyright in a work gives the owner the exclusive right to certain “restricted acts” in respect of that work, and a copyright owner may authorise others to do those acts by licence. Elbakyan is scathing in her blog posts “about so-called copyright law” that was “created to make to taboo free distribution of information”. The fact is Sci-Hub is engaged in large-scale, blatant, and very public copyright infringement, and from an ethical standpoint librarians should support publishers’ efforts to get its services closed down, but not without arguing effectively and advocating for the alternatives at the same time.

This is the website you're supporting.

In the end it's up to you to decide what values you believe in, but if you believe that supporting Sci-Hub is academic, I'll venture that you're in the minority among people who have a clear picture of what Sci-Hub actually does.

Comment: "*In another attack, the hackers not only broke into their database; they changed the names and passwords of profiles. Another institution told us an intruder changed the cell phone numbers linked to the user accounts and also planted malware, meaning that all their computers needed to be completely wiped.*" Nowhere in these sentences is it said that these attacks originate from Sci-Hub. If this was from a source I trust, I'd glance over it, but this is from Scholarly Kitchen and the author is pushing anti-piracy tools. Color me unimpressed. Stealing creds to use as a proxy, this I ...

Comment: ... assume Sci-Hub is doing. Wanton destruction, nope. There is no incentive for Sci-Hub to bite the hand that is feeding them. I agree with the idea that Sci-Hub may be counterproductive to proper liberalization of academic publishing, but it would take much more than closing sci-hub to force academics to switch to open publishing. After all, there is still the arXiv, personal websites, twitter hashtags for sharing files, private collections walking around and more. Academics don't generally believe in the existence of knights in shining armor.

Comment: @darijgrinberg suggest reading the whole article, I cannot quote every relevant part of it. If you choose not to trust it because it's from Scholarly Kitchen and the author is pushing anti-piracy tools, that's up to you, but I'd be curious what kind of evidence you'd accept.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Another example if you dislike this one: https://www.chronicle.com/article/Librarians-Find-Themselves/235353 *Edward Sanchez, head of library information technology at Marquette University ... says that many colleges have been targeted by Sci-Hub. In one case at Marquette, a professor received an email stating that he or she needed to update his or her university user name and password by following a link. Once on the site, which was actually in New Zealand, the faculty member typed in new credentials, which were then captured by what the publisher later linked to Sci-Hub.*

Comment: @darijgrinberg as for what academics can do, read the other link which gives concrete suggestions. It's at the very end of the article.

Comment: It's the implicature that stinks about the ScholarlyKitchen post, not the literal claims they are making. The post quotes cases of Sci-Hub illicitly gaining university credentials, and cases of university credentials being heavily abused (for malware and password change), leaving it to the reader to add 1+1. But nowhere is it made clear that Sci-Hub are sharing the creds they have obtained with miscreants; they could just as well be gaining them from the latter's forums -- and furthermore, some of the heaviest claims state no connection to Sci-Hub at all. The Mabna hackers have never ...

Comment: ... been connected to Sci-Hub to my knowledge, yet the post drags them in by their heads and shoulders.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm concluding that it's impossible to convince you, so I'm not going to bother. Suggest you speak to your institution's librarians about Sci-Hub and see what they say, that's all.

Comment: No, I'm not going to attack your motte. Sure, librarians have good reasons to pursue higher-horse approaches, such as cancellations of subscriptions, and academics have their own set of weapons, such as editorial board flips. Pretty much everyone who sympathizes with Sci-Hub also does what they can to make these happen; but most academics on lower rungs of the ladder can only negligibly contribute in these ways, and either way, it does not address immediate problems like "how can I get this paper this referee is asking me to cite?".

Comment: @darijgrinberg "how can I get this paper this referee is asking me to cite?" That's easy. Ask your librarian. Librarians exist to solve problems like this. I can practically guarantee that your librarian will be able to get you the paper legally. Of course, you can also do the easy thing and use Sci-Hub, which is sort of analogous to "I have the immediate problem of how to cross the road. I could jaywalk, or I could walk 50 meters down the road and use the zebra crossing." Decisions, decisions.

Comment: For the curious: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93341/if-i-request-a-paper-through-my-university-library-must-they-pay-a-substantial

Comment: "_Sci-Hub is generally illegal_," why?

Comment: @user2768 I consider it pretty self-evident that Sci-Hub is illegal. If you don't, please explain what is unclear about it because otherwise I don't know where to start answering your question.

Comment: @Allure Sci-Hub may partake in illegal activities (hosting copyrighted material), but that does not "make them illegal". An entity cannot be illegal by virtue of its existence. There are plenty of out-of-copyright or copyleft documents on Sci-Hub that are legal for them to serve and legal for you to access.

Comment: @forest if you consider an entity cannot be illegal by virtue of its existence, can you name any entity that is illegal?

Comment: @Allure No. An entity may partake in illegal activity, but it cannot itself "be" illegal.