# What are copyright infringement examples in the academia?

Tags: publications, copyright

Does anyone have copyright infringement examples in the Academia?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here. However I wouldn't be worried. Just don't make a habit of doing it without a proxy.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to "solve". If you really feel strongly about giving money to the publishers (it's not the authors who get the money), then I suppose you could buy copies.

Comment: If someone finds out you might get a fine, but that's very rare and more common for people who do it very frequently, or do it for profit. You won't get in trouble for downloading two books unintentionally. Many people use that site frequently and very few get in trouble.

Comment: You might want to ask that on [law.se].

Comment: It was probably downvoted because it's not on-topic here. Academia Stack Exchange doesn't deal with questions of the type "was this legal and will I get in trouble?".

Answer (score 1):

Sure, look at [Sci-Hub](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/what-are-the-consequences-of-using-sci-hub), which is basically a website for sharing copyrighted material typically without the copyright holder's permission. See also [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/112457/is-supporting-sci-hub-illegal-unacademic).

[Apparently I need to more characters to this answer]

Comment: OP changed his question radically, so if it gets reverted, this answer will no longer be relevant.

Comment: As a student am I obliged to contact for permission each publisher of the articles which are free of access online for their permission to use them in my assignments, course papers and other home works for study purposes? If yes that will be insane! :D :D :D

Comment: Oh I have just read that there is Fair Use doctrine! Lol. :D :D :D. Good to know, this is what protects students from using articles without permission! What a relief!